# How can I make `msg!` print to stdout when run off-chain?

Tags: solana-program, logs, invoke

I have code that's used both in my program and off-chain. In the code, I use `msg!`. If that `msg!` line is run off-chain, I get this error:

```
Invoke context not set!
```

What do I need to do to make `msg!` print to stdout instead of throwing this error?

I want to re-use my code. Duplicating it and modifying the new copy is unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "off-chain", ie. in a test or an application, you can set your own override for the syscall at the start of the program. Start by defining a type that implements the syscall stubs:

```
struct SyscallStubs {}
impl solana_sdk::program_stubs::SyscallStubs for SyscallStubs {
    fn sol_log(&self, message: &str) {
        println!("{message}");
    }
}
```

And then at the start of your test / program, you can have your program use those stubs by invoking:

```
solana_sdk::program_stubs::set_syscall_stubs(Box::new(SyscallStubs {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining this macro and using it in place of `msg!`:

```
#[macro_export]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
macro_rules! msg_or_println {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        #[cfg(any(target_arch = "aarch64", target_arch = "x86_64"))]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            println!($($arg)*);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        #[cfg(not(any(target_arch = "aarch64", target_arch = "x86_64")))]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            msg!($($arg)*);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Additionally, I had to suppress warnings about `msg` being an unused import. Unfortunately, this is required, since the warning will appear when compiling off-chain programs (a test, for example) yet the import is necessary when compiling on-chain programs.

```
#[allow(unused_imports)]
use solana_program::msg;
```